# How to sort an associative array by key type and force specific order in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array filled with more or less randomly mixed numeric and string keys, let's go with such example:

```
$arr = array('third'=>321, 4=>1, 65=>6, 'first'=>63, 5=>88, 'second'=>0);
```

Now I'd like to sort it in such way:

1. Sort the array so the numeric keys would be first, and string keys after.
2. The numeric values sholud be in specific order: 5, 4, 65
3. The string keys should be ordered by specific order as well: 'first', 'second', 'third'
4. Output in this case should look like: `array(5=>88, 4=>1, 65=>6, 'first'=>63, 'second'=>0, 'third'=>321)`
5. Each element might not be present at all in the original `$arr`, which might be additional problem...

<s>My guess would be to split the array and make separate one with string keys, and one with numerc keys. Than sort each one and glue them together... But I do't know how to do it?</s>
**Edit: Turned out to be a very poor idea, much better approach is in the answer below.**

Comment: Please include the Stack Overflow questions that you found while researching how to perform a custom sort.  There are MANY.  So that we understand the variability of your task please include 3 or 4 different sample arrays.  We also want to see your best attempt to self solve.  Please read [ask].

Comment: @mickmackusa All that I find does refer to usort(), yet I'm unable to come out with simple function that will do te trick. If You see an question with custom sort solution that is somehow similar to my problem, I'd be grateful for it.

Comment: @Zorann Why `5` before `4` ?

Comment: I am going to hold my answer ransom @Zorann  I have posted and deleted a working solution.  I will only un-delete it after you show proof of research and your best coding attempt.  This is not a trivial task for a young developer, so I will be lenient in my expectations, but I need to see you produce _something_.  I am not doing this to be rude, I am doing this as a compelling way to groom you to be a better question asker.  I look forward to your question edit ...but I am going to bed soon.

Comment: @nice_dev Well, this is the obstacle, otherwise I would't ask the question ;)

Comment: @mickmackusa - I found out what I belive to be the true answer to my question. I'll post it in a minute, yet I'll gladly see Your alternative. I know why You hesitated to answer right away and sent me back to books, yet belive me - I'm not as lazy as You originally thoughtt. I just was'nt able to describe my problem correctly... Anyway - my fault.

Comment: @Zorann That ain't an obstacle but rather an unclear requirement.

Comment: @nice_dev It's unintuitive, true, but this is one of the points of my question - that the expected output of numeric keys are not in order. Forgive me for unclear expression and bad example that caused this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The spaceship operator inside of a `uksort()` call is the only way that I would do this one.

Set up a two arrays containing your prioritized numeric and word values, then flip them so that they can be used a lookups whereby the respective values dictate the sorting order.

By writing two arrays of sorting criteria separated by `<=>` the rules will be respected from left to right.

The `is_int()` check is somewhat counterintuitive.  Because we want `true` outcomes to come before `false` outcomes, I could have swapped $a and $b in the first element of the criteria arrays, but I decided to keep all of the variables in the same criteria array and just negate the boolean outcome.  When sorting ASC, `false` comes before `true` because it is like `0` versus `1`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vXuJm))

```
$numericPriorities = array_flip([5, 4, 65]);
$numericOutlier = count($numericPriorities);
$wordPriorities = array_flip(['first', 'second', 'third']);
$wordOutlier = count($wordPriorities);

$arr = ['third' => 321, 4 => 1, 'zero' => 'last of words', 7 => 'last of nums', 65 => 6, 'first' => 63, 5 => 88, 'second' => 0];

uksort(
    $arr,
    function($a, $b) use ($numericPriorities, $numericOutlier, $wordPriorities, $wordOutlier) {
        return [!is_int($a), $numericPriorities[$a] ?? $numericOutlier, $wordPriorities[$a] ?? $wordOutlier]
               <=>
               [!is_int($b), $numericPriorities[$b] ?? $numericOutlier, $wordPriorities[$b] ?? $wordOutlier];
    }
);

var_export($arr);
```

or ([demo](https://3v4l.org/6DEtQ))

```
uksort(
    $arr,
    function($a, $b) use ($numericPriorities, $numericOutlier, $wordPriorities, $wordOutlier) {
        return !is_int($a) <=> !is_int($b)
               ?: (($numericPriorities[$a] ?? $numericOutlier) <=> ($numericPriorities[$b] ?? $numericOutlier))
               ?: (($wordPriorities[$a] ?? $wordOutlier) <=> ($wordPriorities[$b] ?? $wordOutlier));
    }
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  5 => 88,
  4 => 1,
  65 => 6,
  7 => 'last of nums',
  'first' => 63,
  'second' => 0,
  'third' => 321,
  'zero' => 'last of words',
)
```

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and seems complicated for me (I need to work on the alternative if syntax, vary hard to read for me). What do You think about my approach? Does it have flaws that I missed?

Comment: I am sure I am not fully understanding your requirements (based on your answer).  If you are never expecting any "outlying" keys in your input data, then your way is just fine.  I assumed that you need to accommodate the possibility of keys that were not in your known list.  Another version of your solution would flip your `$proper_order`, then use it to filter `$arr` with `array_intersect_key()`, then call `array_replace()` to generate the desired output.

Comment: @Zor If ALL of your keys are "known", you can use this technique https://3v4l.org/BfrJg but I am 1000% certain that that technique is a duplicate on Stack Overflow, so I will not post it as an answer.

Comment: I really like this linked example - It's like one-line solution versus my entire loop. Looks like I don't know much about stackoverflow, but posting such answer shuld be good idea regardless if it was corredct elsewhere. It's just to good to not be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I was extreamly overthinking the case. I came out with a solution that I was unalbe to implement, and unnecessary I described it and ask for help on how to do this.

Turned out that what I really wanted was extreamly simple:

```
$arr = array('third'=>321, 4=>1, 65=>6, 'first'=>63, 5=>88, 'second'=>0);
$proper_order = array(5, 4, 65, 'first', 'second', 'third');

$newtable = array();
foreach ($proper_order as $order)
{
    if (isset($arr[$order]))
        $newtable[$order] = $arr[$order];
}
unset($order, $arr, $proper_order);

print_r($newtable);
```

The result is as expected, and the code should resist the case when the original `$arr` is incomplete:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 88
    [4] => 1
    [65] => 6
    [first] => 63
    [second] => 0
    [third] => 321
)
```